# Logcat after publishing an app

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I have a question about Logcat.

While debugging in Android Studio it's very useful the tool Logcat which shows 
the **exact line of code** that led to a crash, tipically a NullPointerException,
but also other types.

The basic question is: after publishing an app, is there a way to track the app's crashes
with the same precision?
I mean: in Google Developer Console or other serivces, is there an automatic way to get this info
or the developer must write some code in order to do it?
In the second case, it would be useful some link in order to know how to trace the potential bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the Google Developer Console, there is a menu item on the left side called "Crashes & ANRs" which will provide you all the info you need to investigate a crash. It gives you the app version, android version, device, stacktrace...pretty much everything. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that this detail was available in Developer Console.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

You can integrate some crash reporting tools such as ACRA, CrashLitics etc. There are Free and Commercial versions as well and they provide all the information regarding the crash including line number

There are [lots](https://www.google.lk/search?q=Android%20crash%20reporing%20tool&rct=j#q=Android+crash+reporting+tool).

Answer (score 1):

as other friends said you can use services that provided but also you can create a crash reporting system for your own by using prepared class and methods in java like thread class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is after you publish you have no access to the physical devices when others download/buy your application. The limitation is the user needs internet access. Bug reporting is your solution.

Here's a few options, I've personally used mint-splunk. It works well enough.

https://try.crashlytics.com/

https://mint.splunk.com/

http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring

Comment: Thanks, in case of necessity, I'll take a look at these services.